# save items to azure blob directly use feed exporter

Tags: python, scrapy, azure-blob-storage

I need to save the scraped items to an azure blob container.

I tried using `scrapy-feedexporter-azure-blob` by adding the below to the `settings.py` but it doesn't save anything.

```
FEED_STORAGES = {"azure": "scrapy_feedexporter_azure_blob.AzureBlobFeedStorage"}
FEED_URI = <MY_URI>
AZURE_ACCOUNT_NAME = <MY_ACCOUNT>
AZURE_ACCOUNT_KEY = <MY_KEY>
AZURE_CONTAINER = <MY_CONTIANER>
# AZURE_FILENAME = 'sample.json'
```

I am sure that the container name, URI, account name, and key are correct. I can also save the items locally, but need to export them directly to Azure blob.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using unmaintained software ([3 years without changes](https://github.com/curabase/scrapy-feedexporter-azure-blob/commits/master)). It’s possible that changes in Scrapy prevent it from working.

You could run a Scrapy version as old as the last release of the extension you are using ([1.1.0](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/news.html#scrapy-1-1-0-2016-05-11)?), that should work. It would also be a security risk.

Alternatively, you could work on bringing Azure support to Scrapy itself. If you have a look at [the implementation of Amazon S3 support in Scrapy](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/1.7/scrapy/extensions/feedexport.py#L94), and the implementation of [the extension you are using](https://github.com/curabase/scrapy-feedexporter-azure-blob/blob/master/scrapy_feedexporter_azure_blob/__init__.py), you could send a pull request to Scrapy with a working implementation.